# "In case" or "in cases"?

Tags: word-choice

Which is the right one: *in case* or *in cases*? What's the difference?

For example, what if I'm just trying to FYI a team?

> If in (*case/cases*) you are not sure, we'll be using this form moving forward.

Comment: Depending on the context, either can be correct.  Do you have an example usage?

Comment: What if i'm just trying to FYI a team? For example, if in (case/cases) you aren't not sure, we'll be using this form moving forward.

Comment: "If in case" is saying the same thing twice, and "you aren't not sure" is saying the opposite of what you want to say. The choice of *case* vs. *cases* is your smallest problem. The reader won't care about it, as they will be distracted by these graver issues.

Comment: And don't forget to vote for your preferred answer; helps the next person along who's searching.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the situation in which you're using it.

"In case" would be properly used in this context: *I will bring an umbrella just **in case** it rains.*

"In cases" is less frequently used. It would be properly used in the context of: ***In cases*** when your chest is in a lot of pain, you may need to go to the doctor.

Answer (score 2):

"In case" addresses one specific instance, and is often used in places where you could substitute "if"; "in cases" speaks to a number of different possibilities, and one can substitute "situations" for "cases" in these usages:

> In case this wasn't clear. we alway try to look deeper in cases like this one.

Substituting:

> If it wasn't clear, we always try to look deeper in situations like this one.

Answer (score 0):

"In case" is used when you want to express a consideration, preparation for something may happen in the future
*example*: In case it's rain, I arrive by bus instead of bicycle

"In cases" is used to listing possibilities, events
*example*: In cases customers want to ask for refund, please bring the purchase order

Comment: I would say "in *the* cases *when* customers..." It's not very natural without those extra words.

Comment: I have never heard the construction "in cases" before. Can you add any source?